# MongoDB and horizontally scalable microservices

Tags: mongodb, microservices

## Does MongoDB support horizontally scalable micro services?

Having looked at the documentation I have come to the conclusion the answer is no, at least not without building some additional interface infrastructure.

However I wanted to ask the question in case I am wrong - it might be that MongoDB has a feature which I am not aware of.

### What is a horizontally scalable micro service?

The following describes how I would define a monolith, micro service, and horizontally scalable micro service. Please don't fixate too much on these definitions, they are merely here to help clarify the question.

- A monolith describes a software architecture which consists of a single process which performs a task or set of tasks.
- A micro service architecture is a more modern approach to building software systems. In a micro service architecture, the single monolith is split into multiple independent processes as far as possible. Each process has to perform some functionality which is independent of all others. These processes might be connected together using network connections or via databases.
- A micro service architecture might not be what I would describe as "horizontally scalable". What I mean by this is that if a micro service process performs some operation on data which it obtains from a datastore, then the datastore needs to have a way of distributing data to a set of concurrently running copies of the same micro service process.
- A system like Kafka provides such a facility via the concept of consumer subscriptions. Multiple copies of the same logic (process) can be dynamically spun up or shut down, and the consumer subscribe logic ensures that each unit of data stored in a Kafka topic will be processed by one of those logic instances.
- I don't think MongoDB has such a mechanism, although it would be relatively simple to put a small process in front of a MongoDB instance which provided support for this.

### An example problem

This example is something which I am working on right now. I have a software system which does the following things:

- Queries a website and pulls entire HTML pages (webscraper)
- Splits those HTML pages into individual, independent elements (some collection of HTML divs from each HTML page)
- Extracts data from each div
- Saves the data in a structured way in a datastore

This system used to be a monolith. I re-worked it into a more micro service style system, which looks like a data pipeline, with each operation from the above list of bullet points roughly being an independent process. These processes are "connected together" using MongoDB. (Kafka could equally as well have been used, but some of the HTML documents are large, so to use Kafka would have required some additional configuration and setup.)

The problem with using Mongo is I don't currently understand how it is possible to achieve horizontal scalability. In other words, I cannot run multiple copies of any of these processes and expect the system to function in a sensible way.

**To make it absolutely clear, let's focus on a single step in the chain:**

One of the processes has the task of transforming chunks of HTML (individual div elements) into non-structured documents containing features from the HTML divs.

What the Feature Extractor Process does is this:

- MongoDB has a collection containing HTML divs
- The process queries Mongo for documents in this collection which are tagged with a flag indicating the feature extraction process has not been run yet
- Documents are returned to the process, and the feature extraction logic is run
- A new Mongo document is created containing the extracted feature data
- This document is written to a different MongoDB collection
- Finally, the original HTML div document is updated and the feature extraction flag is set to "true" indicating that it has now been processed and should not be processed again

What I don't understand is how to achieve horizontal scaling:

- If I spin up two copies of this process, what do I have to do to prevent both processes operating on the same document at once?
- If I run multiple processes, and one process queries a collection, do the other processes have to "wait", similarly to how an SQL database locks tables or individual table rows?

It occurred to me that I *could* write a lightweight process which sits in front of the MongoDB instance and provides an API (via a network socket) from which other processes can perform their query for documents.

I am not sure if this would be a necessary component of an architecture to achieve horizontal scalability, or if there is another way to do it using MongoDB directly.